# taking information from camera

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

My function must take picture from camera at the current time I will call him , and keeps it in my buffer , non anywhere else . I don't need to open camera , to push it's "capture" button , I need to do all this automatically. user must not see , that camera is working , and after taking the image , it must copy it only in my buffer . Don't suggest to use `camera.start()` and after copying video or picture , delete it from Gallery please. Can anybody helps me? and Sorry for English :)

Comment: Define "information". (Or is it just the current picture?). And explain in what context it will be used, that makes answering easier.

Comment: I'm sorry , what you meant saying  "in what context it will be used". Thanks

Comment: what will be the purpose of this application

Comment: For example if your phone will be shake , it'll  begun to capture. :)

Comment: Sounds to me like you want to spy on somebody lol you would have to start an intent to access camera so don't see how you could do this without the users knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

**[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity)** is the solution to your problem. Just edit it a little. You can store the bitmaps in an ArrayList for example.

But you know that this is bad for performance as it'll flood the memory? Writing it to the sd is probably a better idea than using the internal memory.

Edit: When using the API, you *have* to show a preview. You can, however, make this preview 1x1px or hide it behind some other view. And you can modify the code a little bit to not have the capture start on a buttonclick, but on whatever you want. I take it you can do that.

**[This](http://handycodeworks.com/?p=19)** can also help a lot

Comment: sorry , but I don't need to open camera , to push it's "capture" button , I need to do all this automatically. user must not see , that camera is working

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, You will not be able to capture the image opening the camera application without the knowledge of the user.